# Twig parses space before variable

Tags: php, twig, symfony

Twig seems to parse the space before a variable as part of the variable's name.
For example, the following piece of template:

```
<td>{{ item.status }}</td>
<td>{{ item.animatorId }}</td>
```

*sometimes* gives me the following exception

```
Variable " item" does not exist in mytemplate.html.twig at line 36
```

Note the space in the name. Line 36 is the second line.
Removing the space between the brackets and the variable fixes it, but it makes the code less readable.

Any idea how to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: That sounds totally weird. Any chance you can make it reproducible?

Comment: @Lumen I'll try but I can't think of any specific circumstances where this happens. In this case the second line was a copy-paste of the first one. Maybe the Unicode character that got there is something else than a space? I'm using Atom on OSX.

Comment: Unicode characters would be my first guess, too…

Comment: Okay, next time this happens I will try to inspect the character that got there and update the question.

Comment: While i wasn't able to fix this issue which happens to me from time to time, i found that deleting the space with a backspace and re-hitting space bar works. Also i would look into the Atom Twig extension (i didn't have it before ... I THINK)